# What would we see if a small black hole hits a large, massive neutron star?

Tags: black-holes, collision, event-horizon, neutron-stars

What would we see if a small black hole hits a large, massive neutron star? I am trying to visualise what would  we see what the event horizon of a small black hole would do to the surface of a very large neutron star but with no success...

Comment: Is the neutron star really essential to the question? If so, then this might be a prerequisite: [How Would a Neutron Star Actually Appear?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/12868). Or would you be content with an answer describing what we'd see if a small black hole hit the earth? And how small is "small"? Marble-sized? (That's still a *lot* of mass, which might be why you'd want to use a neutron star as the target.)

Comment: “Large”, “small”, and “hit” are all vague terms. Hitting how fast? Non-relativistic? Highly relativistic? Slower than the speed of sound in the neutron star? Faster?